# Как записать две csv-таблицы на разные листы через pandas в Python?

Tags: python, pandas

Нужно два листа записать на отдельные страницы в CSV. Сейчас записываю только одну

```
frame = pandas.DataFrame(*лист для записи*)
fileWrite = open(path, 'a', encoding='UTF-8', newline='')
frame.to_csv(fileWrite, index=False, sep=';')
```

Как записать вторую таблицу на другую страницу в этот же файл?
Знаю про `ExcelWriter`, но он не работает с CSV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно -  это хорошо. Вот только вы хотите невозможного. Формат СSV не поддерживает многостраничные файлы. В этом легко убедиться самому. Создайте хlsх файл. Сделайте его многостраничным, а потом попробуйте его сохранить как сsv. Обнаружите, что вам предложат либо сохранять каждый лист в отдельный файл, либо использовать другой формат, который поддерживает многостраничность.

Так что если позарез нужна многостраничность -  используйте to_excel() и формат хlsх. Если позарез нужен csv -  то пишите в этом формате  с помощью to_csv() но в разные файлы.  А "скрестить бульдога с носорогом" не удастся.